# leaflet-routing-machine Nexjs

Tags: next.js, leaflet, react-leaflet

How to implement routing by leaflet in Nextjs.

There are some videos and blogs about routing by leaflet, but not for Nextjs.

Most of them are pure JS and Reactjs.

I'm using leaflet on my Nextjs project without any problem but, I couldn't find any way to implement routing to.